# Buck converter with current and voltage regulators

Tags: buck, buck-boost

I need to find scheme for Buck converter with adjustable output voltage from 0 up to 12V. Also it may have an adjustable current limit. Max current output is 10A or at least 5A. Actually I will need it to make a bench power suply for my future projects.

I just have started with electronics and I want to make it myself, not to buy. I found many schemes but all of them have higher minimum output voltage, sth around 5V. Or they have maximum current around 3A.

I have one idea how to make that but not sure whether that works. Maybe I can reach specs that i need (max current output 5-10A, voltage 0-12V) if i will connect 2 schemes (at image below ) for 3A in parralel. Will it work?
Also it can be a buck boost converter.
[image: http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_circuitos_tut10.php]
Thank you for the help :)

Comment: No, using that scheme isn’t going to deliver what you want to any reasonable degree of performance. The scheme shown is naive in that it uses a 555 timer and there is no analogue voltage feedback to regulate the output. A bench supply needs a much more sophisticated circuit and self protective measures to avoid it burning or melting or just failing.

Comment: A **linear** bench supply that can deliver a few hundred milliamps is a good starter project.  Any power supply that can deliver 120 Watts will be a challenge, as will any switcher.